# frequency spectrum of sinc function in matlab shows me nothing

Tags: matlab, fft, matlab-figure

since i don't have sinc function in my MATLAB,

I implemented that function as shown below

```
    %% time specificactions:
    Fs=10000; dt=1/Fs; t=(-0.1:dt:0.1-dt)'; N=size(t,1);
    %message signal
    mt=(sin(pi*100*t))./(pi*100*t);

    %% frequency specifications
    dF=Fs/N; 
    f=-Fs/2:dF:Fs/2-dF;
    M=fftshift(fft(mt));
    plot(f,abs(M)/N);
```

but the figure shows me nothing but blank, so i looked up the variable table and it is filled with NaN.

One thing I don't understand that is that the exactly same procedure worked pretty well when the function i want to fourier transform was just cosine function.

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that, at `t=0`, you're dividing zero by zero. Try explicitly specifying `mt=1` for `t=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrongly defined `sinc` function, as when `t=0` it outputs `NaN`.

you can check that doing `any(isnan(mt))` in your code.

To define properly the function do

```
mt(find(t==0))=1;
```

That will make your code output

[image]

You may want to reconsider the parameters in order to see better the square wave.

Comment: Thanks! after adding that function, it worked very well

Answer (score 0):

the source code of sinc function in Matlab:

```
function y=sinc(x)
%SINC Sin(pi*x)/(pi*x) function.
%   SINC(X) returns a matrix whose elements are the sinc of the elements 
%   of X, i.e.
%        y = sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)    if x ~= 0
%          = 1                   if x == 0
%   where x is an element of the input matrix and y is the resultant
%   output element.
%
%   % Example of a sinc function for a linearly spaced vector:
%   t = linspace(-5,5);
%   y = sinc(t);
%   plot(t,y);
%   xlabel('Time (sec)');ylabel('Amplitude'); title('Sinc Function')
%
%   See also SQUARE, SIN, COS, CHIRP, DIRIC, GAUSPULS, PULSTRAN, RECTPULS,
%   and TRIPULS.

%   Author(s): T. Krauss, 1-14-93
%   Copyright 1988-2004 The MathWorks, Inc.
%   $Revision: 1.7.4.1 $  $Date: 2004/08/10 02:11:27 $

i=find(x==0);                                                              
x(i)= 1;      % From LS: don't need this is /0 warning is off                           
y = sin(pi*x)./(pi*x);                                                     
y(i) = 1;
```